# VS 2019 AWS Serverless.Template Parse Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, visual-studio-2019, aws-sam

Afternoon,
Trying to use aws toolkit and servless.template to create a lambda that triggers on a schedule and inserts data into an sqs bucket. All is good except for the "Events" line. I am getting an error that says "Parse error on line 24". I have checked, double checked, and verfied the squiggle bracket placement but no go. According to aws documentation, I should be able to establish the events within the lambda definition.

Any help is much appreciated! Here is my code. Parameterized as the app will be deployed via azure across multiple environments.

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "An AWS Serverless Application.",
  "Parameters":{
    "AwsRole" : { "Description" : "Role for lambda expression", "Type": "String"},
    "SecurityGroup" : { "Description" : "List of secuirty group ids, comma delimited", "Type" : "List<String>" },
    "SubNets" : { "Description" : "List of subnet ids, comma delimited", "Type" : "List<String>" },
    "Schedule" : {"Description" : "Cron schedule", "Type" : "String"}
  },
  "Resources": {
    "PopulateQueue": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "SendToQueue::SendToQueue.PopulateSqs::RunPopulate",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Role" : {"Ref" : "AwsRole"},
        "VpcConfig" : {           
            "SecurityGroupIds" : { "Ref" : "SecurityGroup" } ,
            "SubnetIds" : { "Ref" : "SubNets"}
         }   
error here--->"Events": {
          "Trigger":{
            "Type": "Schedule"
            "Properties" : {
                "Schedule" : { "Ref" : "Schedule" },
                "Name" : "PopulateSqsSchedule",
                "Description" : "Schedule for sending items to sqs",
                "Enabled" : false
            }
          }
            
        }
      }
    },
    "SendQueue": {
        "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
        "Properties": {
            "ContentBasedDeduplication": true,
            "MessageRetentionPeriod": 1200,
            "QueueName": "SendQueue"
        }
    }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `}, ` instead of `}` on line 23?

Comment: DOH!!! you are awesome! many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like on line 23 you have a typo - missing `,` after `}`. There's also missing `,` on line 26 as well.

Usually it's very useful to verify your JSON with [some online tool](http://json.parser.online.fr/), which quickly helps you understand the error.